# PL/SQL to select all and more columns

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL Server the following gives me column 50 followed by all the columns. How do you achieve the same with PL/SQL?

select col50, * from mytable

Thanks.

Comment: It is plain `SQL` and not `PL/SQL` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to qualify the *.

```
SELECT col50, mytable.*
  FROM mytable
```

or

```
SELECT col50, t.*
  FROM mytable t
```